# How to run a function inside a cursor in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, cursor

I am very new to cursor. But I am trying to run a self-defined function inside a cursor. The function works. But no data was shown, if the cursor was ran. How can I fix it? Your inputs will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @fName varchar(50), @lName varchar(50)
DECLARE cursorName CURSOR

LOCAL SCROLL STATIC

FOR
SELECT fName, lName FROM TABLEA
OPEN cursorName 

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName
   INTO @fName, @lName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM dbo.data (@lName, @fName) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName
    INTO @fName, @lName

END
CLOSE cursorName 
DEALLOCATE cursorName
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server/TSQL to me. But it doesn't look to me like you're actually doing anything with the cursor that would have any output.  You're just putting the values into variables, and moving along to the next row.  And then there's the argument that cursors are evil (which they are...).

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Comment: Are you after multiple result sets, or would the whole lot in one go be ok?

Comment: The function will extract some data, but I only need the data that is under the names (both first and last name) from table A. Because some names are duplicates, like jenny, I could not figure out a better way to do it.

Comment: Technically what you are doing should work although using a cursor may not be the best way. So dbo.data is a table valued function? Are you sure you aren't passing the parameters out of order? Should it be first name and then last name? Your code should definitely work as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to get rid of the cursor entirely by using [cross apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

```
select
    x.*
from
    tablea a
        cross apply
    dbo.data(a.fName, a.lName) x
```